# Has anyone tried infusing Torani sugar free syrup?

Tags: ingredients

I'd like to make a cocktail recipe I found which uses a Ginger Cardamom Simple syrup, but I can't take all that sugar. I typically use Torani's Sugar free syrup for drinks (which uses Splenda and some gums for viscosity), and I was wondering if anyone has tried infusing flavors into that syrup. If so did you heat it or just let it sit for X days?

Answer (score 1):

I have never personally tried but my advice would be not to heat it.

In the same way that you wouldn't heat a shop bought sugar syrup - you will boil off the water and be left with a thicker syrup and possibly one which would crystallise.

You can either add the ingredients to your Torani's Syrup and leave for X days to see what happens, or follow a recipe to make your own!

Here is one I found for a [sugar-free lavender syrup](https://www.wickedstuffed.com/keto-recipes/sugar-free-lavender-simple-syrup/) which you should be able to amend for a Ginger Cardamon version.